# How can I label array values for accessibility without breaking my chess game?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, accessibility

I have a pretty specific and weird question that I'm hoping to get some help with. Basically, I'm trying to make an accessible chess game with React Native where the squares are labeled and recognizable with VoiceOver. A regular chessboard is named with numbers 1-8 running horizontally and letters A-H running vertically. Practically speaking, the square at the very upper lefthand side of the board would be A1 and the square at the very bottom righthand side would be H8.

The problem that I'm having pertains to how the chessboard is being rendered and how the game itself works. The backend of the game is loosely based off of this [tutorial](https://www.techighness.com/post/develop-two-player-chess-game-with-react-js/) where the chessboard is being rendered like so:

```
const squares = Array(64).fill();

  for(let i = 8; i < 16; i++){
    squares[i] = new Pawn(2);
    squares[i+40] = new Pawn(1);
  }

  squares[0] = new Rook(2);
  squares[7] = new Rook(2);
  squares[56] = new Rook(1);
  squares[63] = new Rook(1);

  squares[1] = new Knight(2);
  squares[6] = new Knight(2);
  squares[57] = new Knight(1);
  squares[62] = new Knight(1);

  squares[2] = new Bishop(2);
  squares[5] = new Bishop(2);
  squares[58] = new Bishop(1);
  squares[61] = new Bishop(1);

  squares[3] = new Queen(2);
  squares[4] = new King(2);

  squares[59] = new Queen(1);
  squares[60] = new King(1);
```

I've tried to use .map like this:

```
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

let grid = squares.map((label, index) => `${letters[Math.floor(index/8)]}${index%8 + 1}`);
```

Similarly, I've tried to hardcode values in like this:

```
squares[0].label = "A1";
```

With no luck because it ends up breaking the movement of the pieces which seem to rely on the array values being integers. I'm still a little bit confused about this part, but the previously linked tutorial shows the backend structure in detail.

Basically, I'm really unsure of what I can do to make this work. Any feedback or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you extend the `Piece` class to include a `label` property?

Comment: Yes!     this.label = label;

Comment: Please include your custom code :) and point out where you are seeing the actual error so we can help you best!

Comment: Note that in chess, usually, A1 is on bottom-left and H8 on top-right, unless you are playing with black pieces.